# What is the reading of 開店時?

Tags: readings, parsing

> 開店時は82歳だった林さんが、慣れた手つきで団子を焼いている ([source](https://mainichi.jp/articles/20210920/k00/00m/040/036000c))
> *Hayashi san, who was 82 years old when she opened the store, makes dumplings with her experienced hands.*

and I was wondering whether to read
開店時【かいてんとき】
or
開店時【かいてんじ】

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Like the English verb *open*, 開店 is ambiguous between *start a new shop* and *open in the morning*. (For the latter, usually most shops open in the morning, I suppose, but it could be in the evening or at night. Anyway for the first time in the day.)

開店時 in the first sense is read as かいてんじ.

開店時 in the second sense can be read both as かいてんじ and かいてんどき of which my impression is that かいてんどき is more common.

The 開店時 in the question is in the  <strike>second</strike> first sense, so it can be read as <strike>both</strike> かいてんじ.

Comment: I'm very confused by your last sentence! In the OP's example, isn't 開店時 actually being used in the first sense you've described -- that is, isn't the sentence saying that Hayashi-san was 82 when the shop **first opened for business**, about eleven years ago? (We're told that she is 93 now.) Or am I missing something?

Comment: @Nanigashi Ah, you're right.  I misread she is 82 yo now.

Answer (score 3):

First of all, it’s never かいてんとき. If it’s not かいてんじ, it must be かいてんどき with a *dakuon*.

I would read it as かいてんじ in either sense of 開店.

かいてんどき sounds to me like a good time for opening a business.

Comment: Thanks. What's the pitch accent on a compound with -時 such as this one?

Comment: @jogloran: The accent is on the mora (or syllable) immediately before [時]{じ}. For example, 逮捕 is [たいほ]【HLL】 but 逮捕時 is [たいほじ]【LHHL】. In the case of 開店時, the pitch falls earlier, resulting in [かいてんじ]【LHHLL】, because てん is pronounced like one syllable. Some people might pronounce it as [かいてんじ]【LHHHL】. When 時 is read as どき, the pitch stays up like [かいてんどき]【LHHHHH】.