# Is the reading of 時【じ】 or 時【どき】here?

Tags: readings, suffixes, time

I asked about the reading of 時 in this post,

[What is the reading of 開店時?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/90444/31150)

where the predominant view seems to be that it is 時【じ】.

Is it therefore also 時【じ】 in this sentence?

子【こ】どもの学校【がっこう】や習【なら】い事【ごと】の送迎時【そうげいじ】にも父親【ちちおや】の姿【すがた】がある

*Fathers are also present when picking up their children from school or lessons.*

https://mainichi.jp/premier/health/articles/20211125/med/00m/100/005000c

If so, can we say that the suffix 時【じ】means a shorter period of time, such as "bed time" or "dropoff/pickup time," whereas the suffix 時【どき】 refers to a longer stretch of time, like a season or period of days?

Just for reference, the wwwjdic entry for each looks like this:

時 【じ】 (suf) (1) hour; o'clock; (suf,adj-no) (2) (See 緊急時) (specified) time; when ...; during ...

時 【どき】 (n-suf,n,adv) (1) (after noun or -masu stem of verb) (See 食事時, 売り時) time for ...; time to ...; good opportunity to ...;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no difference in their meanings.

Basically, within a single word, `onyomi` or `kunyomi` should be aligned. `じ` is usually used with onyomi-words, `とき` is for kunyomi-words. Of course, there are some exceptions...

`送迎時`: Both `送【そう】` and `迎【げい】` are onyomi, so `送迎時` should be`そうげいじ. Other examples: 入店時【にゅうてんじ】, 非常時【ひじょうじ】

`売り時`: `売る【うる】` is kunyomi thus it will be うりどき. Other examples: 潮時【しおどき】, 飯時【めしどき】

`しょくじどき` is an exceptional pattern.

Comment: Of course, there are <del>some</del> *many* exceptions.  #FTFY

Comment: I wrote there's no difference but now I feel that we tend to use じ for specific events and どき for abstract periods of time. For instance, 飯時 means mealtime, not a specific moment that someone has a meal.